# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Learning AngularJS Could use a pointer or two

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am leaning Angular my first application is a photo sharing tool.  I added the code for the upload function and broke it.  I thought I was defining the albumProvider in my controller, but apperently I have failed to do so.  The error is Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider.  I am stuck and could us a hand on what I need to fix.

albumService.js

```
(function () {
  function albumProvider($http,$fileUploader) {
    this.getUploader = function (album_name, scope) {
      return $fileUploader.create({
        scope: scope,
        method: "PUT",
        url: "/v1/albums/" + album_name + "/photos.json"
      });
    };

    this.getAlbums = function (callback) {
      $http.get("/v1/albums.json")
        .success(function (data, status, headers, conf) {
          callback(null, data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, conf) {

          callback(data);
        });
    };
    this.getPhotosForAlbum = function (name, callback) {
      $http.get("/v1/albums/" + name + "/photos.json")
        .success(function (data, status, headers, conf) {
          callback(null, data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, conf) {
          callback(data);
        });
    };

    this.addAlbum = function (album_data, callback) {

      if (!album_data.name) return callback({ code: "missing_name" });
      if (!album_data.title) return callback({ code: "missing_title" });
      if (!album_data.description) return callback({ code: "missing_description" });
      if (!album_data.date) return callback({ code: "missing_date" });
      if (!is_valid_date(album_data.date)) return callback({ code: "bad_date" });

      $http.put("/v1/albums.json", album_data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, conf) {
          callback(null, data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, conf) {
          callback(data);
        });
    };
  }
  photoApp.service("albumProvider", albumProvider);
  function is_valid_date(the_date) {
    if (the_date.match(/^[0-9]{2,4}[\-\/\. ,][0-9]{1,2}[\-\/\. ,][0-9]{1,2}$/)) {
      var d = new Date(the_date);
      return !isNaN(d.getTime());
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
})();
```

albumUploadController.js

```
(function () {
  function AlbumUploadController($scope, $routeParams, albumProvider) {//Dependency Inject albumProvider
    $scope.album_name = $routeParams.album_name;
    $scope.page_load_error = '';
    $scope.description = {};

    albumProvider.getPhotosForAlbum($scope.album_name, function (err, photos) {
      if (err) {
        if (err.error == "not_found")
          $scope.page_load_error = "No such album.  Are you calling this right?";
        else
          $scope.page_load_error = "Unexpected error loading page: " + err.code + " " + err.message;
      } else {
        $scope.photos = photos;
        $scope.uploader = albumProvider.getUploader($scope.album_name, $scope);

        $scope.uploader.bind("completeall", function (event, items) {
          $scope.done_uploading = true;
        });
      }
    });

    $scope.uploader.bind('beforeupload', function (event, item) {
      var fn = _fix_filename(item.file.name);
      var d = item.file.lastModifiedDate;
      var dstr = d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate();

      item.formData = [{
        filename: fn,
        date: dstr,
        description: $scope.descriptions[item.file.name]
      }];
    });
  }
  photoApp.controller("AlbumUploadController", AlbumUploadController);

  function _fix_filename(fn) {
    if (!fn || fn.length == 0) return "unknown";

    var r = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_,]+$");
    var out = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < fn.length; i++) {
      if (r.exec(fn[i]) != null)
        out += fn[i];
    }
    if (!out) out = "unknown_" + (new Date()).getTime();
  }
})();
```

app.js

```
var photoApp = angular.module('photoSharingApp', ['ngRoute']);
photoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/albums", {
      controller: "AlbumListController",
      templateUrl: "/app/partial/albumPartial.html"
    })
    .when("/album/:album_name", {
      controller: "AlbumViewController",
      templateUrl: "/app/partial/albumViewPartial.html"
    })
    .when("/album/:album_name/upload", {
      controller: "AlbumUploadController",
      templateUrl: "/app/partial/albumUploadPartial.html"
    })
    .when("/album/photos/:album_name/:photo_filename", {
      controller: "PhotoViewController",
      templateUrl: "/app/partial/photoViewPartial.html"
    })
    .when("/", {
      redirectTo: "/albums"
    })
    .when("/404_page", {
      controller: "Controller404",
      templateUrl: "/app/partial/404Partial.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/404_page"
    });
});
```

Comment: where do you get the error? service or controller? which provider is failing to inject? it would be better if you narrow down your question.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper  Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=NaNileUploaderProvider%20%3C-%20%24fileUploader%20%3C-%20albumProvider  This is what I see in the console.

Comment: ok, your error is on the file uploader library, which version are you using?

Comment: Where are you actually referencing the module as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up the file uploader in your app configuration like:

```
var photoApp = angular.module('photoSharingApp', ['ngRoute','angularFileUpload']);
```

then as far i know you may change your fileuploader definition for:

```
return new FileUploader({
        scope: scope,
        method: "PUT",
        url: "/v1/albums/" + album_name + "/photos.json"
 });
```

I'm not sure about passing the scope to the service, but you can try that out, also don't forget to update your dependency from $fileUploader to FileUploader

Comment: I tired your code, but the browser throws Failed to instantiate module photoSharingApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)  Thanks for the suggestion.